# Enlazar javascript en dos archivos html

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy empezando a ver javascript y tengo dos paginas html con contenido javascript.
En una tengo un método y en otra tengo que mostrar el resultado de esa función.
He probado a llamarlo en la cabecera y justo antes de llamar al método, pero no me funciona.
Estas son las dos páginas:
js.html:

```
<html><head><title>js</title></head><body>
<script src="C:\Users\cdum7\Desktop\js\js1.html">
document.write(miFuncion(4,5));
</script>
</body></html>
```

js1.html:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script>
function miFuncion(a,b){
    c=a+b;
    return c;
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un archivo que se llame funciones.js y pegas

```
function miFuncion(a,b){
c=a+b;
return c;
}
```

luego la llamada seria la siguiente

```
    <script src="funciones.js"></script>
   <script>

            document.write(miFuncion(4,5));

   </script>
```

Comment: Ya está arreglado. En el archivo de funciones.js, no necesitaba poner las etiquetas de script, y además hay que poner la ruta completa en el src. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: Claro yo en este caso, lo deje en la raiz, pero si tiene que ir la ruta completa. y el js sin las etiquetas de script. de nada

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que mejores la estructura de tu proyecto, puedes tomar una base [de esto.](http://jamiewaxberg.com/WebDesign101/build/)

Teniendo bien estructurado tu proyecto podrías hacer referencia a tu archivo js de esta manera : `<script src="js/main.js"></script>`

Tus archivos de JavaScript siempre deben tener extension .js y para mandar llamar tu funcion dentro de tu documento Html bastaria con llamar la función de la siguiente manera :

```
<script>
    myFunction(4, 5);
</script>
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me funciona: he cambiado la extensión a .js de donde tengo el método y solo le he dejado las etiquetas de script. Además en la página para a mostrar he colocado: `<script src="js.js"></script>` en el head y en el body: `miFuncion(4,5);`